# How can I force Caffe to print the label near each probability or fix the order of their printing?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm trying to analyze probabilities of a binary classifier according to the solution #2 suggested here: [How can I get two output values (for each of the two classes) for a binary classifier in Caffe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993175/how-can-i-get-two-output-values-for-each-of-the-two-classes-for-a-binary-class?answertab=votes#tab-top)
I've got the following output of my testing:

```
I0321 20:27:52.331949 11973 caffe.cpp:276] Batch 1999, accuracy = 0
I0321 20:27:52.332003 11973 caffe.cpp:276] Batch 1999, prob = 0.932919
I0321 20:27:52.332011 11973 caffe.cpp:276] Batch 1999, prob = 0.0670813
I0321 20:27:52.367635 11973 caffe.cpp:276] Batch 2000, accuracy = 0
I0321 20:27:52.367686 11973 caffe.cpp:276] Batch 2000, prob = 0.0507332
I0321 20:27:52.367694 11973 caffe.cpp:276] Batch 2000, prob = 0.949267
```

There is a problem that the two probabilities for each class are not labeled here. So in this particular case for iterations 0-1999 the probabilities are printed in the following order: first the probability for class 0 ("no") is printed and then for class 1 ("yes"). For iterations 2000-2999 it is printed vice versa: (first probability for class 1 ("yes") and then probability for class 0 ("no").
This is not convenient since I further make an automated parsing of this log.
**How can I force Caffe to print the label near each probability or fix the order of their printing?**

Comment: I find it very difficult to believe caffe is actually changing the order of the printed vector. If this is the case, this is a BUG in caffe and should be reported in the github project page. Can you reproduce this behavior? can you show a minimal example (minimal net, two samples) where the order is switched? Could it be the case that example #1999 is of class 0 (and hence 1st entry of prob is higher), while example #2000 is of class 1 (and thus the second entry of prob is higher)?

Comment: Shai, this is reproducible. However it is not shown on cases with less then several thousands examples of each class (and also I've noticed that the reverse order of probabilities continues for exactly one or several thousands of examples).
When I run such testing, I have all example images sorted by classes, so there could not be the case when those two consequent examples belong to different classes. Also I recalculate the total accuracy for the testing and it exactly matches the one printed by Caffe if we consider probabilities for that portion of examples as printed in the reverse order.

Comment: Agreed, could be a Caffe bug, but you need to provide a minimal reproducible example (with data) and report it to the Caffe guys.